# Searching in Listview with searched textcolor highlighted in Listview Android

Tags: android, listview, spannable

I Have a `listview` with `arrayadapter` .. i need to implement this in my music application ... help me out

[image]

```
    public class Search_Class extends Activity {

        EditText searchedit;
        ListView listview3;
        SongsManager songManager;
        Context context;
        String[] abc;
        ArrayList<String> names;
        ArrayList<String> arrayList;
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_search);
            context = getBaseContext();
            searchedit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchedit);
            listview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview3);
            songManager = new SongsManager();
            songsList = songManager.getPlayList(context);
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> obj = songsList.get(i);

                names.add(obj.get("songTitle"));
                arrayList.add(obj.get("songTitle"));
            }

            abc = new String[names.size()];
            abc = names.toArray(abc);

            listview3.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            // ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MySearch.this,
            // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, abc);
            // listview3.setAdapter(ad);
            listview3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting listitem index

                    String[] abc1 = new String[arrayList.size()];
                    abc1 = arrayList.toArray(abc);

                    int songIndex;

                    for (int i = 0; i < abc1.length; i++) {
                        if (abc[position].equalsIgnoreCase(abc1[i])) {
                            songIndex = i;
                            Intent in = new Intent(Search_Class.this,
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                            SharedPreferences sp;
                            sp = getSharedPreferences("lastplayed", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            Editor edit = sp.edit();
                            edit.putBoolean("searchSongIndex", true);
                            edit.commit();
                            in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);

                            in.putExtra("FLAG", true);
                            startActivity(in);
                            finish();

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }

            });
            // ad.notifyDataSetChanged();

            searchedit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // MySearch.this.ad.getFilter().filter(arg0);

                    String text = arg0.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    filter(text);

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

        }

        public void filter(String charText) {
            System.out.println("Text---" + charText);
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            names.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                System.out.println("if---" + arrayList.size());
                abc = new String[arrayList.size()];
                abc = arrayList.toArray(abc);

                // names.addAll(arrayList);
            } else {
                System.out.println("else");

                for (int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {

                    System.out.println(abc[i] + "----" + charText);

                    if (abc[i].toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                        names.add(abc[i]);
                    }
                }
                abc = new String[names.size()];
                abc = names.toArray(abc);
            }
            ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Class.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, abc);
            listview3.setAdapter(ad);
            ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

    }

Just Created A Custom `Listview` Using `ListActivity` 

public class SearchingClass extends ListActivity {
    EditText et;
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> AllSongs;
    String[] AllSongsArray;
    SongsManager songManager;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SearchClass_Adapter adapter;
    int textlength = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searching_class);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        context = getBaseContext();
        songManager = new SongsManager();
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList(context);
        AllSongs = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> obj = songsList.get(i);

            AllSongs.add(obj.get("songTitle"));
        }
        AllSongsArray = new String[AllSongs.size()];
        AllSongsArray = AllSongs.toArray(AllSongsArray);
        setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                textlength = et.getText().length();
                AllSongs.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < AllSongsArray.length; i++) {
                    if (textlength <= AllSongsArray[i].length()) {
                        /***
                         * If you want to highlight the countries which start
                         * with entered letters then choose this block. And
                         * comment the below If condition Block
                         */
                        /*
                         * if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase( (String)
                         * listview_names[i].subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                         * array_sort.add(listview_names[i]);
                         * image_sort.add(listview_images[i]); }
                         */

                        /***
                         * If you choose the below block then it will act like a
                         * Like operator in the Mysql
                         */

                        if (AllSongsArray[i].toLowerCase().contains(
                                et.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                            AllSongs.add(AllSongsArray[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                AppendList(AllSongs);
            }

        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), AllSongs.get(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searching_class, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void AppendList(ArrayList<String> str) {
        setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class bsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Activity cntx;

        public bsAdapter(Activity context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.cntx = context;

        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return AllSongs.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return AllSongs.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return AllSongs.size();
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = null;

            LayoutInflater inflater = cntx.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_artist_name);

            tv.setText(AllSongs.get(position));

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [List View Filter Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android)

Comment: using spannable String to highlighting text

Comment: can you just explain briefly

Comment: read about ForegroundColorSpan

Comment: here is my code ... i think i need to use afterTextChanged

Comment: see the code above and help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first add two function getData and set Data Search to baseadapter

```
   public class bsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity cntx;

    public bsAdapter(Activity context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cntx = context;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return AllSongs.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return AllSongs.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return AllSongs.size();
    }
    public void setDataSearch(String data) {
            this.search = data;
    } 

    public String getData() {
        return this.search;
    }
```

first declare searchData in Search_class

```
public String searchData;
private bsAdapter mAdapter;
```

and declare

```
mAdapter = new bsAdapter(this);
```

then you add condition in text watcher

```
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            textlength = et.getText().length();
            AllSongs.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < AllSongsArray.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= AllSongsArray[i].length()) {
                    if (AllSongsArray[i].toLowerCase().contains(
                            et.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                        AllSongs.add(AllSongsArray[i]);
                    }
                }
              if (textlength == 0) {

                     mAdapter.setDataSearch(null);

                } else {

                    searchData = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                    mAdapter.setDataSearch(SearchData);
                }

         }
            AppendList(AllSongs);
        }
```

and then put this function in baseadapter

```
public static CharSequence highlight(String search, String originalText) {

       String normalizedText = Normalizer.normalize(originalText, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "").toLowerCase();

       int start = normalizedText.indexOf(search);

       Spannable highlighted = new SpannableString(originalText);
        if (start < 0) {
            // not found, nothing to to
            return originalText;
        } else {

            while (start >= 0) {

                int spanStart   = Math.min(start, originalText.length());
                int spanEnd     = Math.min(start + search.length(), originalText.length());

                highlighted.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                highlighted.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(cntx.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_white)), spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                start = normalizedText.indexOf(search, spanEnd);
            }

            return highlighted;
        }
    }
```

and put this

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = null;

        LayoutInflater inflater = cntx.getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_artist_name);

        if(search != null){
                tv.setText(highlight(search,AllSongs.get(position));
            }
            else if (search == null){
                tv.setText(AllSongs.get(position));

            }


        return row;
```

Comment: why don't you using custom list view, it will be easier to identify string to be highlighted

Comment: Taufik , See Th Edited Code Using Custom Listview With Listactivity Now You Can Help

Comment: already edited answer can you check if you need help with that code just call me

Comment: Well i just used your code .. getting error in adapter .. because i have not used any adapter

Comment: adapter.setDataSearch(null);  searchData = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                    adapter.setDataSearch(SearchData);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77691/discussion-between-mochamad-taufik-hidayat-and-quick-learner).

Answer (score 1):

So here i got the code corrected and working fine ...

```
public class SearchingClass extends ListActivity {
    EditText et;
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    static ArrayList<String> AllSongs;
    String[] AllSongsArray;
    SongsManager songManager;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    int textlength = 0;
    public String SearchData;
    private bsAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searching_class);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        context = getBaseContext();
        songManager = new SongsManager();
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList(context);
        AllSongs = new ArrayList<String>();
        mAdapter = new bsAdapter(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> obj = songsList.get(i);

            AllSongs.add(obj.get("songTitle"));
        }
        AllSongsArray = new String[AllSongs.size()];
        AllSongsArray = AllSongs.toArray(AllSongsArray);
        setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                textlength = et.getText().length();
                AllSongs.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < AllSongsArray.length; i++) {
                    if (textlength <= AllSongsArray[i].length()) {
                        if (AllSongsArray[i].toLowerCase().contains(
                                et.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                            AllSongs.add(AllSongsArray[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    if (textlength == 0) {

                        mAdapter.setDataSearch(null);

                    } else {

                        SearchData = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                        mAdapter.setDataSearch(SearchData);
                    }

                }
                AppendList(AllSongs);
            }

        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), AllSongs.get(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searching_class, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void AppendList(ArrayList<String> str) {
        setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class bsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        static Activity cntx;
        static String search;
        String value;

        public bsAdapter(Activity context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.cntx = context;

        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return AllSongs.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return AllSongs.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return AllSongs.size();
        }

        public void setDataSearch(String data) {
            System.out.println("recieved value" + data);
            this.search = data;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return this.search;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = null;
            LayoutInflater inflater = cntx.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_artist_name);
            // tv.setText(AllSongs.get(position));
            System.out.println("search data value" + search);

            if (search != null) {

                tv.setText(highlight(search, AllSongs.get(position)));
            } else if (search == null) {
                tv.setText(AllSongs.get(position));

            }

            return row;
        }

        public CharSequence highlight(String search, String originalText) {

            String normalizedText = Normalizer
                    .normalize(originalText, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                    .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
                    .toLowerCase();

            int start = normalizedText.indexOf(search);

            Spannable highlighted = new SpannableString(originalText);
            if (start < 0) {
                // not found, nothing to to
                return originalText;
            } else {

                while (start >= 0) {

                    int spanStart = Math.min(start, originalText.length());
                    int spanEnd = Math.min(start + search.length(),
                            originalText.length());

                    highlighted.setSpan(new StyleSpan(
                            android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), spanStart,
                            spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    highlighted.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(cntx
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.red)), spanStart,
                            spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    start = normalizedText.indexOf(search, spanEnd);
                }

                return highlighted;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Utility code that I use to highlight search key in search results,Hope this may help you to implement some part of your application

```
public void setTextAndhighLightSearchKeytest(String searchKey,String searchResult, TextView textView) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(searchKey) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(searchResult)) {
        String searchResultLowerCase  = searchResult.toLowerCase(Locale.UK);
        String searchKeyLowerCase  = searchKey.toLowerCase(Locale.UK);
        int start = searchResultLowerCase.indexOf(searchKeyLowerCase);
        int end = start + searchKey.length();

        if (start > -1 && start < searchResult.length() && end < searchResult.length()) {
            SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(searchResult);
            builder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            textView.setText(builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar use case and am using your utility code.  But its is only highlighting the first occurrence of the search string.  So if search for "e" in the word "screen" only the first "e" is highlighted and not the second one.  Any thoughts or ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
String your_val = filteredList.get(position).getYourValue();
        int startPos = your_val.indexOf(searchString.toUpperCase());
        int endPos = startPos + searchString.length();
        Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(
                Your_value
        );

        if (startPos >= 0) {
            spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(mContext.getResources().getColor(your_color)), startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spanText.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }



        viewHolder.tvInfo.setText(spanText);
```

just put this code in your getView methhod of bas adapter with your value

```
ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, abc){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                String your_val = filteredList.get(position).getYourValue();
                int startPos = your_val.indexOf(searchString.toUpperCase());
                int endPos = startPos + searchString.length();
                Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(
                        Your_value
                );

                if (startPos >= 0) {
                    spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(mContext.getResources().getColor(your_color)), startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    spanText.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
                viewHolder.tvInfo.setText(spanText);
                return your_view;
            }
        };
```

Comment: i am not using custom listview

Comment: ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Class.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, abc);

Comment: You can also override getView method in your ad
ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Class.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, abc){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            }
        };

Comment: Throwing many errors 1)- ViewGroup cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Well I just Created a Custom listview with An Adapter