# Search function in custom listview android

Tags: android, listview

I have implement a custom listview with a search functionality. When i run the code and type an alphabet in the search box, my application clash. Can anyone help me? thank you.

**AllProductActivity**

```
public class AllProductActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
//private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private SweetAlertDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser2 jParser = new JSONParser2();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchResults;

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;


// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://gemini888.tk/test4/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
public static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String TAG_PID = "uid";
public static final String TAG_NAME = "itemname";
public static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
public static final String TAG_PATH = "path";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    final EditText editsearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchBox);

    //testing
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
    {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    searchResults=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(productsList);



    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { //edit search
        //Event when changed word on EditTex
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String searchString=editsearch.getText().toString();
                int textLength=searchString.length();
                searchResults.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++)
                {
                    String searchName = productsList.get(i).get("TAG_NAME").toString();
                    if(textLength<=searchName.length()){
                         if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(searchName.substring(0,textLength)))
                             searchResults.add(productsList.get(i));
                    }
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                 int after) {


               }

               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


               }
              });
    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ViewDetailsActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductActivity.this);
        //pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        //pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        //pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        //pDialog.show();

        pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(AllProductActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
        pDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#A5DC86"));
        pDialog.setTitleText("Loading products. Please wait...");
        //pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();


    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String iname = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                    String path = c.getString(TAG_PATH);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, iname);
                    map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                    map.put(TAG_PATH, path);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

        adapter=new LazyAdapter(AllProductActivity.this, productsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
    }
  }
  }
```

**LazyAdapter**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

private class ViewHolder
{
 ImageView thumb_image;
 TextView pid, itemname, price;

}

ViewHolder viewHolder;


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
     return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.pid = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.pid);
    viewHolder.itemname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
    viewHolder.price = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.price);
    viewHolder.thumb_image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); //

    vi.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder) vi.getTag();


    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    viewHolder.pid.setText(song.get(AllProductActivity.TAG_PID));
    viewHolder.itemname.setText(song.get(AllProductActivity.TAG_NAME));
    viewHolder.price.setText(song.get(AllProductActivity.TAG_PRICE));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(AllProductActivity.TAG_PATH), viewHolder.thumb_image); //




    Animation animation;
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.slide);
    //animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, (position > lastPosition) ?
        //  R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
    vi.startAnimation(animation);

    return vi;
}

}
```

**Error Log**

```
 05-28 23:01:59.237: E/InputEventSender(1261): Exception dispatching finished signal.
 05-28 23:01:59.247: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261): java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at mygp.gptrade.AllProductActivity$1.onTextChanged(AllProductActivity.java:99)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7467)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9183)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:223)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5532)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5343)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7665)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2035)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1505)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2418)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1962)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3558)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2010)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1704)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1695)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1987)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 05-28 23:01:59.367: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1261):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 05-28 23:01:59.387: D/AndroidRuntime(1261): Shutting down VM
 05-28 23:01:59.387: W/dalvikvm(1261): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2affba8)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): Process: mygp.gptrade, PID: 1261
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at mygp.gptrade.AllProductActivity$1.onTextChanged(AllProductActivity.java:99)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7467)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9183)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:223)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5532)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5343)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7665)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2035)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1505)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2418)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1962)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3558)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2010)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1704)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1695)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1987)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 05-28 23:01:59.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at

```
         mygp.gptrade.AllProductActivity$1.onTextChanged(AllProductActivity.java:99)
         String searchName = productsList.get(i).get("TAG_NAME").toString();
         not "TAG_NAME"(String) , is TAG_NAME(Constant) .
```

good luck

Comment: ok, now my application run well, but my list not updating when i search any key words, any idea?

Comment: Set filtered ArrayList "searchResults" adapter in ListView by adding

adapter=new LazyAdapter(AllProductActivity.this, searchResults);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to implementing searching in custom `listview`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.demo.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

then your activity is like this

```
public class SearchingClass extends ListActivity {
    EditText et;
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    static ArrayList<String> AllSongs;
    String[] AllSongsArray;
    SongsManager songManager;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    int textlength = 0;
    public String SearchData;
    private bsAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searching_class);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        context = getBaseContext();
        songManager = new SongsManager();
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList(context);
        AllSongs = new ArrayList<String>();
        mAdapter = new bsAdapter(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> obj = songsList.get(i);

            AllSongs.add(obj.get("songTitle"));
        }
        AllSongsArray = new String[AllSongs.size()];
        AllSongsArray = AllSongs.toArray(AllSongsArray);
        setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                textlength = et.getText().length();
                AllSongs.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < AllSongsArray.length; i++) {
                    if (textlength <= AllSongsArray[i].length()) {
                        if (AllSongsArray[i].toLowerCase().contains(
                                et.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                            AllSongs.add(AllSongsArray[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    if (textlength == 0) {

                        mAdapter.setDataSearch(null);

                    } else {

                        SearchData = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                        mAdapter.setDataSearch(SearchData);
                    }

                }
                AppendList(AllSongs);
            }

        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), AllSongs.get(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searching_class, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void AppendList(ArrayList<String> str) {
        setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class bsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        static Activity cntx;
        static String search;
        String value;

        public bsAdapter(Activity context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.cntx = context;

        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return AllSongs.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return AllSongs.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return AllSongs.size();
        }

        public void setDataSearch(String data) {
            System.out.println("recieved value" + data);
            this.search = data;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return this.search;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = null;
            LayoutInflater inflater = cntx.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_artist_name);
            // tv.setText(AllSongs.get(position));
            System.out.println("search data value" + search);

            if (search != null) {

                tv.setText(highlight(search, AllSongs.get(position)));
            } else if (search == null) {
                tv.setText(AllSongs.get(position));

            }

            return row;
        }

        public CharSequence highlight(String search, String originalText) {

            String normalizedText = Normalizer
                    .normalize(originalText, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                    .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
                    .toLowerCase();

            int start = normalizedText.indexOf(search);

            Spannable highlighted = new SpannableString(originalText);
            if (start < 0) {
                // not found, nothing to to
                return originalText;
            } else {

                while (start >= 0) {

                    int spanStart = Math.min(start, originalText.length());
                    int spanEnd = Math.min(start + search.length(),
                            originalText.length());

                    highlighted.setSpan(new StyleSpan(
                            android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), spanStart,
                            spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    highlighted.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(cntx
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.red)), spanStart,
                            spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    start = normalizedText.indexOf(search, spanEnd);
                }

                return highlighted;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: or refer this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206679/searching-listview-with-searched-textcolor-highlighted